# Grails: What causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in NameRegistry.getIdFor?

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy

I get the following stacktrace in a Grails 2.0.4 Application:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6170
        at com.springsource.loaded.NameRegistry.getIdFor(NameRegistry.java:44)
        at com.springsource.loaded.NameRegistry.getIdOrAllocateFor(NameRegistry.java:59)
        at com.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.getTypeIdFor(TypeRegistry.java:756)
        at com.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter$RewriteClassAdaptor$RewritingMethodAdapter.rewritePUTSTATIC(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:789)
        at com.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter$RewriteClassAdaptor$RewritingMethodAdapter.visitFieldInsn(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:708)
        at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:280)
        at com.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:83)
        at com.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.methodCallRewrite(TypeRegistry.java:767)
        at com.springsource.loaded.agent.ModifyDefineInClassLoaderForClassArtifactsType.modify(ModifyDefineInClassLoaderForClassArtifactsType.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.define(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:86)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:84)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.defineClassAndGetConstructor(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:84)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.compilePogoMethod(CallSiteGenerator.java:217)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createPogoMetaMethodSite(CachedMethod.java:228)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.createCachedMethodSite(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.createPogoMetaMethodSite(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:183)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPogoCallCurrentSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3022)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallCurrentSite(CallSiteArray.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
        < actual call site in my code, some method call to the same service the original method is in>
```

Apparently my google-Fu has lost me, or nobody has ever had that problem before. Not even searching for just `com.springsource.loaded.NameRegistry` yields any results.

The problem usually goes away after trying the same operation a few times more, but that is hardly a solution.
Any hints on what I could look for?

My wild guess is that Spring is proxying the method I am trying to call, and somehow fails to look it up in its own registry. How can that be my fault?

edit:
The first Line in the Stacktrace that causes this is a harmless method call, like the call to `foo` in the method `bar` in this:

```
class FooService {
      def foo(bla, bloerk) {
          1
      }

      def bar() {
          foo(1,2)
      }
}
```

Comment: what call is it that generates this?

Comment: As already mentioned, it is a call to a method in the same service (my own service). I hope my example clarifies this.

Comment: Not an answer, but the springloaded stuff is the reloading agent introduced with Grails 2.  If you run it with `grails -noreloading run-app` it will probably make it work, but that's a workaround rather than a solution...

Comment: Makes sense, but developing grails without code reload is such a major pain that I'd rather live with these Exceptions. And if I am not mistaken, this also occurs in production..

Answer (score 2):

Actually I see this quite alot when doing batch updates using GPars.
I've worked around the problem by adding failed entries to a retry pool that executes after
the batches have completed. However I'm not all that happy with the solution. But since the feature isn't really critical and runs every other hour or so it just gives a minor update glitch for objects that are seldom updated.

I never see this in production mode just in development mode, so I think it has to do with the dynamic reloading abilities of the classLoader in some way.
I'm also often seeing this type of error at the begining of batch-runs, when the JVM warmed up things just flow along nicely. 
I'm going to take a deeper dive into this problem. If I find something more useful I'll post back.

Just figured I'd reply to your post to tell you that you're not alone.

I'm on Mac OSX running: 
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)

And I've seen this issue all through Grails 2 -> 2.1, don't think I saw it in 1.3.5->1.3.7

Comment: Not sure this is a viable option. I seem to have mitigated this issue by bumping my JVM to 7_u5. Once I updated the following lines in BuildConfig.groovy the error went away. grails.project.target.level = 1.7
grails.project.source.level = 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Either you are trying to read/store a number that is negitive, or store/read a number that is > array.size().

Comment: As can be clearly seen from the stacktrace, it is not me who is trying to reading from an array, but some Spring class, with about 20 stack frames in between.